# Intermittent "Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter'" Error

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project that includes an ASP.NET WebAPI component.

Intermittently, I get the following error:

> Could not load type
>   'System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter' from
>   assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

with the source error pointing to my `GlobalConfiguration.Configure()` call:

```
Line 35: { 
Line 36:     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
Line 37:     GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //<-- error here
Line 38:     FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); 
Line 39:     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

In my register, I am doing the following to return JSON by default:

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
                 .FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");

if (appXmlType != null)
{
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
}
```

(*not sure of the source, but found somewhere on this site as a way to return JSON by default, unless the caller asks for something else*)

I'd like to continue to return JSON as the default content type going forward.

The project includes two other (non WebAPI) websites (that are MVC5), which hit the WebAPI site.

Here's the interesting thing:

- This **DOES NOT** happen when the application is deployed (to Azure)
- This only happens occasionally
- Typically, I run one of the MVC5 sites in the debugger and see this issue
- If I navigate directly to the WebAPI site after the above, I'll get the "Yellow Screen of Death" with the error as per above
- Sometimes, even after a cold reboot, this error will NOT appear, other times it will

What I currently do to work around the problem:

- If I run the WebAPI site in the debugger, if the error is present, it will fixed itself
- After running in the debugger (per above), I can relaunch an MVC5 site in the debugger and the issue goes away

Just to repeat, this **DOES NOT** happen ***ever*** when the application is deployed to Azure.

I have multiple developers working on this project, and we all run into the same error at some stage.

I am referencing the following Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (version 5.2.3)
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (version 5.2.3)
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (version 5.2.3)
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin (version 5.2.2)
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (version 5.2.3)

If I look inside the `*.csproj` file, I have a reference to the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I've checked the `bin` folder of the website, and all the assemblies inside it have the correct version as per the above list (including **System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll**).

Also note that, during debugging and development, each of the three websites are run under `Local IIS` (constraints of external resources force us to do this), so I have:

- `http://localhost/site1`
- `http://localhost/site2`
- `http://localhost/api`

It's becoming cumbersome to get into a debugging session, to get this error, to then stop debugging, launch the API site under the debugger, and to then switch back to what I was doing at the start.

Not sure where else to go to track down what is happening here.  Any ideas?

**Update - 26 July 2016**

Still have this happening.  Since posting the question, have updated the WebAPI to run in its own Application Pool, but that doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Try setting `"Copy to local"` to true for the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` reference

Comment: Thanks for the comment - `Copy to local` is has been set to `true` for some time now - does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Probably your `bin` folder (when deploy) contains one `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`; remove it and the runtime `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` will be used.

Comment: @josejuan - late reply I know, but this is done multiple times, including clean builds and fresh machines, and the issue always comes back.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalled Web API 2 NuGet package
Installed Web API 2 NuGet package again.

Comment: I'll give this a go and see what I find.  I doubt it will fix this as a new developer who has recently cloned the repo fresh also runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about it wrong. Try setting JSON as your default media formatter like this:

```
// first clear all formatters
config.Formatters.Clear();
// Since JSON is the first added, 
// it will be the "default" if no Accept header present
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
// You can choose not to add these back if you never want to use them, 
// up to you.     
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: While I have made this change, it has made no difference to the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had added what was possibly an incorrect version of System.Net.Http.Formatting to my Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and started getting

```
Could not load type 
'System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter' from assembly
'System.Net.Http.Formatting
```

errors in my Webservice. After removing this System.Net.Http.Formatting dll from GAC my webservice started working again.

Answer (score -1):

when you build looks for any warning that talks about conflict. Double-clicking on the warnings injects the compatible versions in the  section of web.config. This obviously can be done manually also.